# Datatable no pagina carga los resultado pero no crea la paginacion

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, datatables

Tengo un probelma raro, que armo la datatable con los datos de ejemplo y me funciona todo, el buscador y la paginacion, pero cuando cargo los datos de la base no me hace la paginacion y tampoco el buscador, alguien que tiene mas conocimientos me podria ayudar con eso?
Lo raro es que tengo otras datatable con datos del servidor y local que funciona perfecto.
Les dejo el codigo como estoy haciendo.

**JS**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/css/select.bootstrap5.min.css" />
      
    <script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script-datatable.js"></script>
```

**script-datatable.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            select: true
            
        } );
        } );
```

**TABLA CON CONSULTA QUE ME MUESTRA LOS DATOS**

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="20%">APELLIDO </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
include("../conectar.ini.php");

$consulta = "SELECT j.apellido, j.nombre, j.pais, j.club, pj.cant_partido, j.puesto, p.valoracion, c.nombre_club, c.id_club,
       COUNT(pj.cant_partido) AS partidos_jugados, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partido p2 WHERE p2.id_jugador = j.id_jugador AND p2.valoracion > 0) AS partidos_valorados, ROUND(AVG(p.valoracion), 2) AS promedio_valoracion FROM jugador j LEFT JOIN partidos_jugados pj ON j.id_jugador = pj.id_jugador_p LEFT JOIN club c ON j.club = c.id_club LEFT JOIN partido p ON j.id_jugador = p.id_jugador GROUP BY j.id_jugador";
$respuesta = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
    

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)){
?>
<tbody>
     <tr>
    <td><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
<?php
    }       
?>
    
</table> 
<?php
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

Por las dudas probe solo con el nombre y pasa lo mismo, me muestra todos los resulados sin paginacion ni busqueda.

Ya rebusque en la doc oficial y no dice nada.

Alguein tiene alguna idea de lo que puede esta pasando?

Gracias de antemano.

Repito, ese mismo codigo si pongo los valores de ejemplo funicona todo.

Ya probe varias versiones del JS, ya los puse abajo los js, arriba y nada, no se que pasa.

Tendra que ver la consulta sql?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que intentas hacer, porque veo que creas una tabla con php e iteras los resultados para poblar esa tabla... siendo que si declaras un datatable y le pasas un coleccion de datos se crea y se pobla el datatable de manera automatica.
Leiste la documentacion de datatables?

Comment: El problema es que la datatable no me esta paginando los resultados y tampoco funciona el buscador

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging

Comment: @David081 ya use  "paging": true, pero lo mismo sigue sin paginar los resultados y me muestra todos de una sola vez, con como 2500 resultados

Comment: Voy a responder con un ejemplo de como yo uso los datatables, para que tengas una idea porque segun yo... creo que no lo estas usando correctamente y espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

La ventaja de cuanto usas la libreria de `datatables` , es que no necesitas nada mas que pasarle la coleccion de datos con la que quieres poblar tu datatable y lo demás se hace solo, Acá un ejemplo:

supongamos que en un recupero una coleccion de datos con la siguiente estructura:

```
let users = [
   {nombre:"ejemplonom1", apellido :"ejemploap1"},
   {nombre:"ejemplonom2", apellido :"ejemploap2"},
   {nombre:"ejemplonom3", apellido :"ejemploap3"}  
]
```

Para poblar el datatable tengo que inicializar el datatable y  pasarle la informacion y los parámetros de configuración:

```
$("#tablaEjemplo").DataTable({
   data:users,//Aca le paso la coleccion de datos,
   paging: true,//paginacion en true,
   columns: [//Le indico el nombre que tendra cada columna y campo usar de users
      {title:"nombre", data:"nombre"},
      {title:"apellido", data:"apellido"}
   ]
   
})
```

De esta forma yo creo mi datatable, sin iterar la coleccion, sin siquiera manipularla...DataTable hace todo con los parametros de configuracion que le haya pasado al declarar el datatable.

Comment: Ya lo hice tal cual comentas arriba,  de esa forma me muetra la paginacion pero cuando traigo los datos de la base de datos no me muestra la paginacion. Lo raro es que tengo otras paginas con datatable y con muchos registros y si me muestra la paginacion, no se que esta pasando, ya se me quemaron los libros, gacias igual

Comment: como le estas pasando la informacion al datatable?

Comment: Como esta en la pregunta

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses una peticion ajax para obtener los datos via javascript (cliente-servidor), y luego hacerlo como te muestro.. eso te lo facilitara todo, saludos.

Comment: ya lo hice tambien, igual no me trae la paginacion, me trae todos los resultados en una sola pagina, en un principio estaba echo con ajax como tengo los otros dos y otro lo tengo con datatable solo porque son pocos datos.